# What portion of 3rd party android library is included when generating apk?

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

I use many 3rd party libraries like AndEngine, ButterKnife, Parse, Picasa etc in my Android app.

Does it mean I have to include all of them into my APK?
For example, I only use one static method from the Picasa library to load images:

```
Picasa.load(image, this, null, null);
```

Yet I still have to add the whole jar file as a supported library in my Eclipse IDE.

When the APK is generated, does it somehow catch/include only specific methods from 3rd party library, or does it include the whole library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Proguard is what you're looking for:

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

> The ProGuard tool shrinks, optimizes, and obfuscates your code by
>   removing unused code and renaming classes, fields, and methods with
>   semantically obscure names. The result is a smaller sized .apk file
>   that is more difficult to reverse engineer.

Make sure you test thoroughly after you start using it, since it has a tendency to be overly-aggressive sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I don't know is it a good option or not. I took the code from the libraries source code whatever related method, class and listener i need. Then I added to my project. That is it. I did not add the whole jar. But I don't know in your case, is it possible to get the source code or not.

Comment: This is generally speaking not a great solution. It makes upgrading the 3rd party library really hard, among other problems.

Comment: What i mean, If you need only specific one feature and it wont change future.

Comment: Sure. I'm not saying it's NEVER appropriate. Just that it's usually not the best way to go. "won't change" is usually a bad assumption. Sometimes I only find bugs in 3rd party libraries after using them for a year.  Also, I'm not a lawyer but I'd imagine there may be cases where a license requires you to do something differently if you've copied or modified the code vs included as a library, so make sure you check first.